# Pure CSS triangle looks blurry in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, blurry

I'm trying to use the pure css triangle used in this article in CSS tricks http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/ but the look blurry in firefox 14. Can I fix it somehow or is it just that FF doesn't render it correctly?

EDIT: Here's an screenshot of how it looks like http://awesomescreenshot.com/0fcf904eb I thought it was a general issue so I just put a link to the article sorry about that

Comment: Instead of pointing to the tutorial, how about posting a link to your example or an image?

Comment: Sorry about that, I just edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `border-style: dotted;` will get rid of the blurry edge on FF. Basically, anything but `border-style: solid;` should work. It might be fixed in FF latest but I definitely experienced the same problem as you, but couldn't test on different FF versions.

For the record I was on FF (15 I guess) winXP

Comment: Just a note: this breaks in FireFox 21. You'll start getting really nasty half/half colors with anything but solid color.

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same issue. Turns out it was something with my Graphics Driver.

Check the `Anisotropic Filtering` settings in your 3D Graphic Driver. I had mine set to `Override Application Settings` and `16x`. After changing it back to `Use Application Settings` and restarting Firefox, the blurriness went away.

Comment: I had the same issue as the asker, and this solution fixed it for me (for my nVidia graphics card).

Comment: Been thinking for the past week that Firefox had a bug because I wasn't seeing the blurry CSS in Chrome or other browser. After restoring my nVidia settings to default, everything looks normal again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Screen grab would be good. This might be something that will differ from device to device, monitors, etc. Have you looked at your results on different devices? I'd tend to think that this will be beyond your control.

Comment: Now that you mention it I just tested on another PC with Win7 and a CRT monitor and it looks fine, it might be something unrelated to FF then, any ideas?

Comment: ... no, not really, it's sort of what it is. Your option is to use css or image since you have no control over what browser/hardware combo will be used for viewing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
-moz-transform: scale(.9999);
```

I got the issue solved.