# CSS arrow breadcrumbs are looking blurry in firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, breadcrumbs

My arrow breadcrumbs are looking kinda blurry in firefox but fine in chrome, opera and ie. [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvVBwj)

Here's how it looks like in firefox:

[image]

My HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="tab-progress btn-breadcrumb clearfix text-center">
    <div class="arrow-nav col-xs-4">1</div>
    <div class="arrow-nav col-xs-4">2</div>
    <div class="active-arrow arrow-nav col-xs-4">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
  padding: 3em;
  background: #B9B9B9;
}
.row {
  background: white;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .arrow-nav:not(:last-child):after {
  content: " ";
  display: flex !important;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 27px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-bottom: 27px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-left: 10px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 33%;
  margin-top: -17px;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .arrow-nav:not(:last-child):before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 27px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-bottom: 27px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-left: 10px solid #E6E6E6;
  position: absolute;
  top: 33%;
  margin-top: -17px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .arrow-nav {
  padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .arrow-nav:first-child {
  padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .arrow-nav:last-child {
  padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
}
.active-arrow {
  background-color: #2a53a5;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.active-arrow .numberCircle {
  color: white;
}
.active-arrow:hover {
  color: white;
}
.active-arrow:after {
  display: flex !important;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 17px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-bottom: 17px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-left: 10px solid #2a53a5 !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -17px;
  border-radius: 0;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="tab-progress btn-breadcrumb clearfix text-center">
    <div class="arrow-nav col-xs-4">1</div>
    <div class="arrow-nav col-xs-4">2</div>
    <div class="active-arrow arrow-nav col-xs-4">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pure CSS triangle looks blurry in firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301366/pure-css-triangle-looks-blurry-in-firefox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i have an understanding of what you want but you CSS is a little out.

Ive set the `active-arrow` to be the one that actually creates the arrows so it knows exactly which one to do it on regardless of its position.

```css
body {
  padding: 3em;
  background: #B9B9B9;
}
.row {
  background: white;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .arrow-nav {
  padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .arrow-nav:first-child {
  padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
}
.btn-breadcrumb .arrow-nav:last-child {
  padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
}
.active-arrow {
  background-color: #2a53a5;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.active-arrow .numberCircle {
  color: white;
}
.active-arrow:hover {
  color: white;
}
.active-arrow:before {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 25px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-bottom: 25px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-left: 10px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.active-arrow:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 25px dotted white;
  border-bottom: 25px dotted white;
  border-left: 10px dotted rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.arrow-nav:last-child.active-arrow:after {
  border: none;
}
.arrow-nav:not(.active-arrow):before {
  content: '';
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid grey;
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  top: 0;
}
.arrow-nav:not(.active-arrow):after {
  content: '';
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  right: -9px;
  top: 0;
}
.arrow-nav:last-child:not(.active-arrow):after,
.arrow-nav:last-child:not(.active-arrow):before {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="tab-progress btn-breadcrumb clearfix text-center">
    <div class="arrow-nav col-xs-4">1</div>
    <div class="arrow-nav col-xs-4">2</div>
    <div class="active-arrow arrow-nav col-xs-4">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="tab-progress btn-breadcrumb clearfix text-center">
    <div class="arrow-nav col-xs-4">1</div>
    <div class="active-arrow arrow-nav col-xs-4">2</div>
    <div class="arrow-nav col-xs-4">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="tab-progress btn-breadcrumb clearfix text-center">
    <div class="arrow-nav col-xs-4">1</div>
    <div class="arrow-nav col-xs-4">2</div>
    <div class="arrow-nav col-xs-4">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what I still need is a divider between them, that line is displayed blurry in Firefox

Comment: Yes! and you make it look really easy, I should step up my game :D

Comment: @Eli: Stewart's answer is good. You would find this one also a bit useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636373/how-to-make-this-arrow-in-css-only/28196665#28196665 (not a dupe as your question is different but linking just to help).

Comment: @Stewartside thanks a bunch, I hope that one day I can be as good as you